# Uppercase after last space in string

Tags: c#, linq

I want change a string so that the character after the last space becomes an uppercase:

```
"a"        => "A"
"aa"       => "Aa"
"aa b"     => "aa B"
"aa bb cc" => "aa bb Cc"
```

Is there an easy Linq syntax (or any other shorthand notation)?

Comment: linq is really about querying, not modifying. Why do you require a linq expression?

Comment: Why doesn't [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) work for you?

Comment: TextInfo.ToTitleCase will not work, only the last word should start with an uppercase char, not all words.

Comment: This seems more a work for a Regex expression than a Linq one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems more a task for a regular expression than a Linq one.

For example you could write a method like this

```
string ConvertLastWordToUpperCase(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\w+$", 
        m => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m.Value));
}
```

And call it with your test strings

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertLastWordToUpperCase("a"));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertLastWordToUpperCase("aa"));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertLastWordToUpperCase("aa b"));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertLastWordToUpperCase("aa bb cc"));
```

At this point you could also execute the conversion using Linq using something like this

```
List<string> testCase = new List<string>()
{ "a", "aa", "aa b", "aa bb cc"};
var result = testCase.Select(x => ConvertLastWordToUpperCase(x));
```